# Is it possible in Mendeley to jump back in a pdf after clicking an internal link?

Tags: reference-managers

I'm using Mendeley for reading my PDFs. Is it possible to click an internal link in a pdf, and then use some shortcut to get back precisely to the position where I started at?

For large pdfs, this might save quite some scrolling time.

Alt+Left, Ctrl+[ did not work, and also nothing else I have tried.

If this doesn't exist, do you know a different reference management system with an embedded pdf viewer that can do this?